# html jump first to included anchor link url

Tags: javascript, html, include, anchor

I have included multiple html in a master html.
When I first enter the browser url

```
indexTest.html#BTestStart
```

the page does not jump to the #BTestStart anchor link,
which is nested in an included html.

But if I press enter again in the url dialog
the page then jumps to #BTestStart anchor link.

My question is,
how can I get the page to jump to the #BTestStart anchor link
when url is first (not second) entered ?

Thank you for any suggestions.

---

**indexTest.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<head>

<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("IH");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("IH");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1 id="ATestStart" IH="ATest.html"></h1>
<h1 id="BTestStart" IH="BTest.html"></h1>

</body>
</html>

<script>
includeHTML();
</script>
```

---

**ATest.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<h2 id="ATestStart">ATestStart</h2>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2 id="ATestMid">ATestMid</h2>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2 id="ATestEnd">ATestEnd</h2>
```

---

**BTest.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<h2 id="BTestStart">BTestStart</h2>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2 id="BTestMid">BTestMid</h2>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2 id="BTestEnd">BTestEnd</h2>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is a timeline of what's happening when the page loads:
  1. The browser obtains indexTest.html from the server
  2. The browser processes the anchor link in the url (the #BTestStart portion) and is unable to find the anchor so it ignores it.
  3. The browser begins execution of the page's javascript and begins rendering the page.
  4. The javascript inserts the contents of the other files into the page.
  5. The browser isn't jumping to that anchor because it doesn't exist when the browser first loads the page.
  6. You reinput the url and it doesn't reload the page because it's the same url, but it does reprocess the url and find the anchor and jump to it

A way to get around this would be to write a function that after all external portions of the page are loaded would tell the browser to reprocess the url.

This function will do the equivalent of selecting the url and pressing return.

```
function recheckURL(){
    var currentUrl = document.URL,
    urlParts = currentUrl.split('#');
    var url = urlParts[0] + (urlParts.length > 1) ? "# " + urlParts[1] : "";
    if (urlParts.length > 1) location.href = "#"+urlParts[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aidan Lovelace
for the detailed explanation and function sample.
However even when I add this function,
entering the url twice is still required to jump to the anchor...
Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
alert("Page Reload Required")
if(localStorage.getItem("reload") != "1"){
    localStorage.setItem("reload","1");
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
else{
    localStorage.removeItem("reload");
}
</script>
```

This kinda works, but it requires the 
extra step of the user clicking on the alert.

I know there is a simple solution to this issue, 
but with lack of javascript fundamentals 
I've spent hours online searching for clues ...